# Un-Initialized object when using pointers

Tags: c++

I am trying to work with pointers - you know experiment.

My code will work fine if I remove the pointer for name and the dereferences for 
`this->name`. But I wouldn't really be learning anything.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string dogsbreed[3];

struct dog
{
 string *name;
 string breed;
 int age;

     void set_dogs_breed()
     {
         dogsbreed[0] = "Collie";
         dogsbreed[1] = "Poodle";
         dogsbreed[2] = "Pit Ball";
    }

    void set_dog_name(string names)
    {
        *this->name = names;
    }

    string get_dog_name()
    {
        return *this->name;
    }
};

int main()
{
    dog doggies;
    doggies.set_dogs_breed();
    doggies.set_dog_name("Socks");
    doggies.get_dog_name();

}
```

In regards to

```
void set_dog_name(string names)
{
    *this->name = names;
}
```

Everything works fine - makes sense, name is a pointer, I dereference name in   `set_dog_breed()` and change it's value.

```
string get_dog_name()
{
    return *this->name;
}
```

Causes

> 29:23: warning: 'doggies' may be used uninitialized in this function
>   [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
>
> 35:9: note: 'doggies' was declared here

OK doggies is uninitialized but the compiler didn't mind when I wasn't using pointers - I am unclear as to why this is required or even if that is the actual issue.

Comment: Why make `name` a pointer to a string? If you are doing so you will need to create a `string` for it to point to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning message is correct, the `doggies` object *is* uninitialized, you never initialize the member variables which has to be done in a constructor.

And since you don't initialize the object, the member variable `name` will have an *indeterminate* value and using the variable in any way except to initialize it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The compiler doesn't stop you from doing bad things, it might detect them but it isn't required to do anything about it. And C++ doesn't have any kind of run-time checking either, the compiler and run-time system will happily let you shoot yourself in the foot.

Also, if you mostly use the dereference operator to access a pointer then you probably don't need a pointer in the first place.

Comment: OK that makes sense,  so if I initialize the member I get an error 11:17: error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}' in initialization - I though it was a string

Comment: @gxminbdd No, `name` is a *pointer* to a string. Why do you need it as a pointer?

Comment: Hey I don't need it to be a pointer, I am just trying things out and trying to figure out what the issue is with certain things. your are right a pointer to a string. But the error message suggests its a char pointer or I am reading it wrong

Comment: @gxminbdd Then you need to make the pointer actually point somewhere. Either to another existing `std::string` object, or using dynamic memory allocation using `new`.

Answer (score 0):

The member `string *name` has no memory allocated for it. So you'd get a segmentation fault inside `set_dog_name`, where you assign another `string` to it.

Additionally, you don't initialize the members either in-class or in a constructor. This perhaps is pointed out by the compiler. GCC 5.2 however shows no warnings or errors, with both `-Wall` and `-Wextra`. I just get a segmentation fault when running the program. Live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8586fc343f4e88d7).

**Aside:**
Initializing the global `dogsbreed` array is in no way the `struct`'s concern. Instead you could make the variable as the `struct`'s [static member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) and initialize it separately.

```
struct dog {
static string dogsbreed[3];
};

string dog::dogsbreed[3] = { "Collie", "Poodle", "Pit Ball" } ;
```